# MacBook Pro unresponsive for a few minutes after opening the lid, AirPort trying to reconnect to wifi

Tags: macbook-pro, airport

I have a problem every time my 2010 MacBook Pro wakes up after I opened the lid.

The symptoms are as follows:

- The display is completely normal, I can see the latest program I used, the top bar menu, the dock, everything
- Moving the mouse is ok, and so is typing
- **Clicks have no effect**
- **AirPort is trying to connect to a network**
- Sometimes the network I usually use can't be found and I have to turn AirPort on & off to make it reconnect

This is really annoying!

I use a 2010 MBP which runs Snow Leopard 10.6.8. The problem has occurred ever since I bought it.

Does anybody have the same problem? Is there any remedy steps I can take?

Any help is appreciated,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the network channel solved the problem!